# Omitting subject in informal letters

Tags: informal-language, correspondence

I have used two sentences in a informal letter in IELTS exam - at the beginning and at the end of the letter. But I'm doubtful about that two sentences(below) because they are without a subject.

> 1. Hope everything is going well with you. [at the start]
> 2. Looking forward to see you soon. [at the end]

I also have another doubt about the second sentence. Should it be:

> Looking forward to **see** you, Or looking forward to **seeing** you

Can you please tell me if those two are acceptable in an informal letter?

Comment: Is "Hope everything in going well with you" correct, or was that supposed to be "Hope everything **is** going well with you? That's the only thing that doesn't make much sense in your question.

Comment: @NoirAntares Thanks for pointing that. It supposed to be "is"; careless typing mistake, sorry about that. So do you  think both the sentences are acceptable.

Comment: Good to know, I'll put up my answer in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Hope everything is going well with you. [at the start]
> 2. Looking forward to see you soon. [at the end]

The (1) sentence is completely fine. It is called [conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask). Some examples:

> (Have you) Seen any good movies lately?
>
> (I will) See you later.

I would never use (2). `Look forward to` is an idiomatic phrase that must be followed by a noun or noun phrase. Examples:

> I'm looking forward to <s>meet</s> meeting your parents.
>
> I look forward to our next conversation.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Hope everything is going well with you. [at the start]
> 2. Looking forward to see you soon. [at the end]

In an informal letter, using these sentences as beginning and ending sentences are very much acceptable as it is commonly used.

> Looking forward to **see you** vs **seeing you**

Both *to see* and *seeing* are actually interchangeable in this case, it's just a matter of which sounds more natural. As infinitives (to see) and gerunds (seeing) can both be used as subjects or complements.

This question really explains it in better detail: [How does one know when to use a gerund or an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-an-infinitive)